# Format string % without multiply the value by 100

Tags: c#, string-formatting

I need to format the string as `%` but the user will enter the number already as `%`

i.e user enter `10`, I need to show `10%`

I tried `{0:P}` and `{0:0%}` but it always multiply the user number by `100`

How can I simply add `"%"` to the input number without multiply it by `100` in the format `{0:}?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two real options, add the % by hand

```
String.Format("Example: {0}%", userValue);
```

or devide the user number by 100 before you display it.

```
String.Format("Example: {0:P}", userValue / 100.0); //don't just do "100" or you will get errors from integer division if userValue is a int.
```

Comment: This worked for me {0}% because I can do it in the designer of the table without using code behind. Thanks

Comment: You never mention a table in your question. If you want to know how to format text in a table then ask about formatting text in a table.

Comment: It is ok. {0}% this is fine

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just append `%`:

```
userEnteredNumber.ToString() + "%";
```

Comment: Calling `ToString` seems redundant to me.

Comment: @Muctadir Right but I prefer explicit type casting. Shows the intention better.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
var showString = userInput + "%";
```

Then display `showString` wherever you need to show.

Answer (score 0):

We use this format for formatting int value to percent without multipying by 100.

```
intPercent.ToString(@"0\%");
```